# Confusing broken imports with Python3 and Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I finally made the jump from python2 to python3 (hooray). However, I'm now plagued with import errors that I cannot seem to sanely resolve.

I have the standard Django 1.8 layout like this:

```
foo_bar
    | - foo_bar
            | - settings.py
            | - urls.py
    | - app_one
    | - app_two
    | - manage.py
```

My problem comes in when I try to import something from another app. For instance, importing a model from `app_one.models.py` into `app_two.views.py`.

I receive server errors depending on what I do.

**1. Absolute Import**

```
# in app_two.views.py
from foo_bar.app_one.models import MyModel
```

This gives the error:

```
No module named foo_bar.app_one
```

If I toggle my project back to 2.7, this import of course works A-OK. Not to mention, PyCharm is able to resolve this path and do auto-complete. So.. it's very confusing.

**2. Relative imports:**

```
# in app_two.views.py
from ..app_one.models import MyModel
```

This gives the error:

```
attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Again, same thing, seems like it should work -- even PyCharm thinks it should work (and can again autocomplete from the path). However, whenever I run my server, it explodes when this view is loaded.

**Kind of Resolving:**

Now, I *can* get the imports to work, but in a way that seems to make zero sense. If I leave off the top level package and abandon the relative import notation, it *will* import without error.

```
# in app_two.views.py
from app_one.models import MyModel
```

But this makes even less sense to me than everything else! Why does this work??? This one, of course, breaks when I swap back to 2.x. Further, PyCharm (for what it's worth), shows this as an unresolvable import.

Comment: Use this format: `import app_one` for import     `app_one.models.MyModel` for using.

Comment: I do not know about django, but is `manage.py` run when you are getting the errors?

Comment: try    from app_one.models import MyModel

Answer (score 0):

For importing for Foreign Key relationships in a model (in Django 1.8+), you do not need to import explicitly, but can use string quoted version:

```
# in app1, import Customer from app2
customer_fk = models.ForeignKey('app2.Customer')
```

Complete Example:

```
from django.db import models

# this app is 'cart'
class ShoppingCart(models.Model):
    # Import Customer Plan from another app - account
    plan = models.ForeignKey('account.CustomerPlan')
    started = models.DateTimeField()
    cart_id = models.BigIntegerField()
```